# How to improve the functionality of the multimedia keys in Windows

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, vlc-media-player, multimedia

I'm using an `SK-8135` `Dell` keyboard- the one with the volume knob. I was wondering how
I could improve its 'integration' in Windows. for example, when I'm using `RythmBox` in `Ubuntu` pressing the `next` key causes the next song to play even when it's not the active window. This is different in `Windows`. When I'm using `VLC` for example the window has to be
the active one so that the `next` or `previous` song plays. The volume knob affects the system sound so that's not a problem. I'd like to be able to change the song while browsing or
coding.
NOTE: I'm not using a `Dell` desktop, I just bought the `Dell` keyboard because it's really
cool. I have a `Veriton`(Acer) desktop computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure this inside VLC:
Tools > Preferences > Hotkeys
then click under "Global" and press hotkey combination.

BTW, in my opinion VLC isn't the best choice for music, it's a bit heavy on resources for music and when you play\pause it takes him a few seconds to fully stop.
I use Foobar 2000 (after trying several other music players), it's very light on resources (though I've seen others even lighter) and it has many available plugins.

Comment: I've tried setting the global hotkey to next but it only works when `VLC` is the current window. I've tried `Foobar 2000` and it does what I want to do, the thing is, it doesn't play video. I want to do what `Foobar 2000` does in `VLC`.

Comment: Sorry about that. It works now, after a restart. Thanks.